# Generalization of $\gamma$ as limit involving primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, euler-mascheroni-constant

The following limit is utilized in Merten’s theorem.

$$
\gamma = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(-\log\log n - \sum_{p\text{ prime}}^n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)
$$

I’m interested in the generalization

$$
C_x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(x\log\log n - \sum_{p\text{ prime}}^n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)\right)
$$

For $x\ge 1$.  Obviously we can define it in terms of the first equation. In fact for $x=1$ we can say $C_1 = \log\zeta(2) - \gamma$, but for $x\gt 1$ we are left with an unresolved product of primes.

Can we derive a definition of this limit that’s not in terms of primes? Perhaps we can modify a proof of Mertens.

It may be helpful to note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\Omega(k)}}{k^s} = \prod_{p\text{ prime}}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x}{p^s}\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Unclear what you expect.

Comment: @reuns I revised my question

Answer (score 2):

Adding $x$ times the limit that gives $\gamma$ and the one that gives $C_x$ gives

$$C_x+x\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\sum_{p\leq n}\log\left(1+\frac xp\right)-x\log\left(1-\frac 1p\right)\right)$$

$$=-\log\left(\prod_p \left(1+\frac xp\right)\left(1-\frac 1p\right)^x\right).$$

This expression is easier to [search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cprod_p%20%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bp%7D%5Cright)%5Cleft(1-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bp%7D%5Cright)%5Ex%24&p=1), and this way I found a few threads mentioning it, notably [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3717439/883143). It doesn't look like it has a known closed form.