# With $N$ a constant $>0$, show $\prod_{p<x}\frac{1}{p^{N+1}-1}>\frac{0.2}{\log^2 x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, products

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037753/is-frac1e-gamma-log-x-prod-limits-p-x-p-textprime-fracpp-1/1038058#1038058).

Show that if $x$ is large enough,$$\prod_{\substack{p<x \\ p \ \text{prime}}}\frac{1}{p^{N+1}-1}>\frac{0.2}{\log^2 x}.$$
Speaking of which, Theorem 6.12, and maybe others, of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf) might be useful.
If $N$ cannot be arbitrarily large for the inequality to hold, any conditions for truthfulness regarding its value are welcome.

Comment: Why do you mention $\gamma$ in your title? It doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: @user37238 Oops, yeah, sorry for that. It's kind of a typo due to the other question. And, I'm gaga. Correcting.

Comment: @user37238 Do you have any idea as to the proof of this?

Comment: @user37238  Or disproof. In fact I am concerned with  the inequality of the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality is equivalent to $$-\underset{p\leq x}{\sum}\log\left(p^{N+1}-1\right)>\log\left(0.2\right)-2\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right).$$
 Now we have, for partial summation and Prime Number Theorem, that exists $c_{1},c_{2}>0$
  such that $$-\log\left(0.2\right)-\underset{p\leq x}{\sum}\log\left(p^{N+1}-1\right)<-\underset{p\leq x}{\sum}\log\left(p\right)=-\left(c_{1}x+c_{2}\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+o\left(\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}\right)\right)<-cx<-2\log\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)$$
 for some $c>0$
  and $x$
  large enough. So it is false.

Comment: As it is written, your disproof is correct. (I'd still be thankful if you answered the original question)
Since I don't know well enough the implications of PNT, could you please provide a reference?

Comment: You can find the inequalities I used here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: more precisely, there are $A,B>0$ such that $$\pi\left(x\right)=A\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+\left(B+o\left(1\right)\right)\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)^{2}}$$ for $x\rightarrow\infty.$ It's one of the forms of PNT.

Comment: I see, thank you. Any ideas as for the other question?

Comment: Not now, but I will work on it ;)

Comment: Do you think that inequality is true?

Comment: I don't know now, I will try something.